# Recursive SUM using DATEDIFF with record VALUE UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-update, partitioning, datediff

I am working on implementing a points tracking system for monitoring performance.  The employee's objective is to have as few as points as necessary.  There is a points system in place that allows an employee to reduce their points by performing better for various periods of time. Points reduced by up to 1 for 30 days of performance, 2 points if they reach 60 days without incident, and 4 points if they reach 90 days without incident.  They cannot accumulate a negative value, and points roll off from oldest date to newest.  The sample table below is a representation of an existing table that has been imported into SQL Server 2012 Database.

```
Employee    Points    Date  Previous    Note
Smith, Joe  0.25    3/21/2013       
Smith, Joe  1       4/1/2013        
Smith, Joe  0.25    5/6/2013        
Smith, Joe  0.5     5/8/2013        
Smith, Joe  1       7/10/2013       
Jones, Tom  1       4/10/2013       
Jones, Tom  1       4/18/2013       
Jones, Tom  0.5     4/22/2013       
Jones, Tom  2       6/25/2013       
Jones, Tom  0.25    7/26/2013       
Jones, Tom  0.25    7/28/2013
```

Because of the dynamic use of data, going to multiple sources such as C#, Excel, Email, there is a need to build deterministic functions and generate either a Table or View that is updated that will display something similar to the following.  The example below would be as the report would look were it pulled on May, 18, 2013.  1 point would have been rolled off of each of the Employees.  Because Joe's first point was .25, it would be set to 0, and the next point which was 1.00 would be reduced by the remaining .75 to a value of .25.  Because Tom had 1 full point as his first point, it would be subtracted from the 1 point, resulting in 0 points for that date.  The function should also notate the previous value of the Points Column before updating the Point value.  The function should supply a note as to the reason for altering the point, the date would be nice in the note field, but a seperate Column for NoteDate could contain the date.  The function can run on a INSERT/UPDATE trigger as there is very low daily usage.  It should check current date with last point date.

```
Employee    Points  Date    Previous    Note
Smith, Joe  0.00    3/21/2013   0.25    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 05/01/2013
Smith, Joe  0.25    4/1/2013    1.00    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 05/01/2013
Smith, Joe  0.25    5/6/2013        
Smith, Joe  0.50    5/8/2013        
Jones, Tom  0.00    4/10/2013   1.00    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 05/22/2013
Jones, Tom  1.00    4/18/2013       
Jones, Tom  0.50    4/22/2013
```

By today's date of 08/24/2013 the results should reflect the following.  Joe would have a total of 0 points, and Tom would have a total of 2 points, and by the 28th would have only 1 point.  There are approximately 2,000 records so it would be difficult to alter these manually.  With the nature of this system and it's implementation it would be possible to run 1 script to reconcile the current records, and have a seperate script to manage ongoing entries.

```
Employee    Points  Date    Previous    Note
Smith, Joe  0.00    3/21/2013   0.25    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 05/01/2013
Smith, Joe  0.00    4/1/2013    0.25    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 06/07/2013
Smith, Joe  0.00    5/6/2013    0.25    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 06/07/2013
Smith, Joe  0.00    5/8/2013    0.50    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 06/07/2013
Smith, Joe  0.00    7/10/2013   1.00    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 08/10/2013
Jones, Tom  0.00    4/10/2013   1.00    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 05/22/2013
Jones, Tom  0.00    4/18/2013   1.00    Rolled Off by System - 60 Day Policy 06/21/2013
Jones, Tom  0.00    4/22/2013   0.50    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 07/25/2013
Jones, Tom  1.50    6/25/2013   2.00    Rolled Off by System - 30 Day Policy 07/25/2013
Jones, Tom  0.25    7/26/2013       
Jones, Tom  0.25    7/28/2013
```

I began using the following on the EmployeePerformance TABLE, to create a view to show the number of days between each record for each employee by their ID.  Then I used a DENSE_RANK() to number each employee with all of the information from the Attendance VIEW.  My original thought was to use an incrementing VARIABLE to cycle through a WHILE loop for each employee, then checking the DATE_DIFFERENCE to see if there are any values greater than 30.  If not I had planned on INSERTING all records for that employee into a final table, and removing them from the Attend2 Table.  Much more scripting than I think is necessary.  I thought instead about using CURSOR, to create a one-time pass, and then another function once reconcilled.  I have little experience with CURSOR though.

```
CREATE VIEW Attendance AS
SELECT A.ID, A.FullName, A.EmployeeID, A.AttendanceDate, A.OccurrenceAmount, A.Comments, A.RecordCreatedDate, A.RecordCreatedUser, (DATEDIFF(DAY, A.AttendanceDate, B.AttendanceDate))*-1 AS DATE_DIFFERENCE
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY AttendanceDate) AS Row_Num, * 
FROM dbo.EmployeePerformance) AS A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY AttendanceDate) AS Row_Num, * 
FROM dbo.EmployeePerformance) AS B
ON A.EmployeeID=B.EmployeeID AND A.Row_Num=B.Row_Num+1  


SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Attendance.EmployeeID) AS Row_Num
INTO dbo.Attend2
FROM dbo.Attendance
```

I have a few ideas I can think of to resolve this, but I am hoping that someone might have had a similar situation or worked with a problem like this before.  I would much rather build this into a concise piece of code I can trigger and with the SQL database being used in a low volume enviornment I am not terribly worried about performance, but I would like to find a good solution that will also keep performance in mind.  Thanks for any help or feedback you may have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your approach/desired result fully, but for starters you can use `LEAD` instead of `JOIN`/`ROW_NUMBER()` to get the `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT ID
     , FullName
     , EmployeeID
     , AttendanceDate
     , OccurrenceAmount
     , Comments
     , RecordCreatedDate
     , RecordCreatedUser
     , DATEDIFF(DAY, AttendanceDate, LEAD(AttendanceDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY AttendanceDate))*-1 AS DATE_DIFFERENCE
FROM dbo.EmployeePerformance)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i completely forgot about LEAD, and it would make it easier than using a self join.  As for the result/approach I can certainly understand, it isn't as easy as I originally thought.  The net problem is this...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i completely forgot about LEAD, and it would make it easier than using a self join.  As for the result/approach I can certainly understand, it isn't as easy as I originally thought.  The net problem is this...I have well over a 1,000 records that have points ranging from .25 to 2.  SO... the desired result is to take these 1,000+ records and first update and roll off any points that need to be based on the rules.  Then to continue to roll off points from that point on based on the business rule of 30, 60, and 90 days.